# Print specific SOAP response

Tags: php, soap

I have the soap response from the client side using:

```
Array (
 [return] => Array (
 [responseCode] => 200 [responseMessage] => SUCCESS [subscriberProfile] => Array (
 [entry] => Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [key] => SUBSCRIBER_IDENTITY [value] => 1234567890 ) ) ) ) )
```

and the php code to print it:

```
Response Code: <?php echo $profile->return->responseCode; ?> - <?php echo $profile->return->responseMessage; ?><br />
Identity: <?php echo $profile->return->subscriberProfile->entry->SUBSCRIBER_IDENTITY; ?></br />
```

The response code printed on the browser, but not for identity. Any idea why? I think is path not called correctly

also tried something like: `<?php echo $profile->return->responseCode->subscriberProfile->entry[0]->SUBSCRIBER_IDENTITY; ?></br />`

Thanks,

Comment: after entry you need to give the index name not the value name. "SUBSCRIBER_IDENTITY" is value not index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `entry` value is an array of objects containing `key/value` pairs, you have to find the right key to be able to output its value. Try something like this:

```
foreach ($response->return->subscriberProfile->entry as $entry) {
    if ($entry->key == 'SUBSCRIBER_IDENTITY') echo $entry->value;
}
```

Output:

```
1234567890
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2to5p)